# Is it correct to use a cron job for a notification programme?

Tags: python, notifications, cron

I'm making a small reminder/note-taking programme for myself, and I have a lot of it set up. All that I'm wondering is if it'd be correct for me to make a cron job for each note. This cron job would run `notify-send` whenever a note was set to take place. If this is the correct method, how would I go about doing this?

Comment: What is `note-send` supposed to do?

Comment: Sorry, corrected. I made a mistake. I have a .bashrc alias which turns `notify-send` into `note-send`. I meant `notify-send`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since this is a personal project, that is ok I would say. It is quick and simple, as well as using pre-existing tools available to you (crontab in this case).

The downside of it, it is making the solution / programme OS dependent. What if someone ever wants or needs to use this on Windows? It would not not work as crontabs are not available in that OS.

For making it OS independent / portable, you should include the ability to manage, control notification and trigger them in your program. This would of course require it to be spawn as a server, so keep track of tasks and notifications on them.

How far do you want to go? That is the question.

Comment: I don't want to go as far as this being used past *nixes or *BSD's, so I feel comfortable using a cron tab